# Scripts to documents (Matlab's publish functionality in python)

Tags: python, matlab, reporting, report

Matlab has this great tool called [publish](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/publish.html). This tool converts a regular matlab script with minimal formatting stuff into structured, nice looking reports (HTML, LateX, RTF). It is capable of handling graphics, mathematical formulae etc.

Is there a similar tool for Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [pyreport](http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/pyreport/). It captures the "captures its output, compiling it to a pretty report in a pdf or an html file".  With this, you can write scripts that print out your source, getting a nice report in the end.